# Where can I find the package for "External Content Library templating assembly" for Tridion sites 9.6

Tags: sdl-tridion, ecl

I am trying to get the source code for "External Content Library templating assembly" for Tridion sites 9.6.

I have cross checked all below path to find out, till couldn't find out.
https://github.com/RWS/dxa-content-management
https://github.com/rws
https://github.com/RWS/dxa-modules

Does anyone have anything that might help me?

Comment: That should be shipped as part of Tridion itself... IIRC

Comment: If I look at one of my 9.6 environments, I have Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Templating.V2.dll in \%TRIDION_HOME%\bin\ - if it's not present, can you check you have "External Content Library" selected when modifying the Content Manager installation?

Answer (score 1):

The "External Content Library templating assembly" is part of the Tridion Sites product and is not Open Source.

Comment: Thanks RIck for your update. I have downloaded the latest from Template builder and its created under Default template.